# Magento 2- Product list sorting issue for alphanumeric product name

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-sorting

I am facing problem in product list sorting by product name if the name is **alphanumeric**, Such as "Facewash, 50ml", "Facewash, 200ml" and "Facewash, 500ml".

**Expected result:-**
"Facewash,**50ml**", "Facewash,**200ml**" and "Facewash, **500ml**".

**Actual Result:-**
"Facewash,**200ml**", "Facewash, **5ooml**", "Facewash,**50ml**".

Below are the screenshots of configuration settings and the frontend list page.

[image: Configuration Setting]

Product List page.

[image: Product list page]

Please suggest what I suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more custom attribute for ordering or adding integer values to make order proper.

ie. you need to add ml in custom field in integer value.

then you can create plugin for modify collection data set by using plugin.

Here is an example.

> app\code\vendor\extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="catalog_productlist_toolbar_plugin" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Product\ProductList;
class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        if ($currentOrder == "name") {
            $dir = $subject->getCurrentDirection();
            $collection->getSelect()->addAttributeToSort('your_attribute', $dir)->order('name '.$dir); // you can add filter as per your requirement.
        }
        return $proceed($collection);
    }
}
```